# Zoom effect on the marker in GoogleMaps Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, google-street-view

In the "private void setUpMap ()" I am using the zoom but when I open the application, loads straight to the marker according to the zoom that put "20".

Questions:
Is there any way to get a zoom effect as you enter the application?
Does anyone know how to add StreetView?

Thank U.

My code:

```
    private void setUpMap() {

    double lat = -23.610928306941542;
    double longi = -46.6690567;
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, longi);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longi)).title("Shopping Ibirapuera"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
}
```

Comment: I dint get you question, may be you asking for **animateCamera**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to animate camera movement you can use mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdate update) method
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)

Example:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-23.610928306941542, -46.6690567)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-23.610928306941542, -46.6690567), 5.0f));

    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20f);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom, 5000, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I made the changes but the result remains the same. The camera effects must be out of my "setUpMap()"? With the changes: private void setUpMap() {
double lat = -23.610928306941542;
double longi = -46.6690567;
LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, longi);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longi)).title("Shopping Ibirapuera"));

CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, longi));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20);
mMap.moveCamera(location);
mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
} @Vadim Savyolov

Comment: @LuizHenriqueUgliano I have edited my answer. Please try now, it should work.